# Spark CSV reader - malformed JSON content inside CSV last column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in a CSV file like below:

```
1,2,3,{col1:1,col2:2,col3:3}
1,2,3,{col1:2,col2:2,col3:4}
1,2,3,{col1:3,col2:3,col3:3}
```

Read this data with Spark code to have output in this format in the dataframe:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
2,2,4
3,3,3
```

I tried several approaches using quoting, and a custom schema. However, I was not able to correctly have all the data in the dataframe. Using a custom schema, I was able to read to a *df* like below (truncated after first "`,`"):

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
1,2,3,{col1:1
1,2,3,{col1:2
1,2,3,{col1:3
```

Comment: have you tried what I have suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your CSV separator is also used in the JSON column without it being escaped or the column being quoted. The best option would be to ask your source to deliver a better formatted CSV file (or use a different separator).

If that is not an option, you can split the file yourself after reading it. For your example, this can can be done as below. Here we read the CSV content as a text file and split it up to the 4th comma. From the resulting array, we select the columns we want.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.text('data.csv')
cols_to_split = 4
splitted = F.split(F.col('value'), ',', limit=cols_to_split)

df.select([splitted[i].alias(f'col{i}') for i in range(cols_to_split)]).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+--------------------+
|col0|col1|col2|                col3|
+----+----+----+--------------------+
|   1|   2|   3|{col1:1,col2:2,co...|
|   1|   2|   3|{col1:2,col2:2,co...|
|   1|   2|   3|{col1:3,col2:3,co...|
+----+----+----+--------------------+
```

Note that your real data might be more complex or structured differently and this solution might not work. The *split* function takes a regular expression as pattern so you can write something which works for you.

Finally, note the `limit` parameter has been supported since Spark >= 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the `from_json` function.

Define the schema for the JSON column:

```scala
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType
json_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("col1", IntegerType()),
        StructField("col2", IntegerType()),
        StructField("col3", IntegerType()),
    ]
)
```

**Sample snippet**

Parse the JSON string into a struct

```scala
df = df.withColumn("c4", from_json("json_str", json_schema))
```

Comment: There were two completely different writing styles here. Was the last part generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)? Or was it copied from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue and it got resolved when i have used ***escape*** option

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='True', delimiter=",", escape='"').load(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CSV Read Example").getOrCreate()

json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("col1", IntegerType()),
    StructField("col2", IntegerType()),
    StructField("col3", IntegerType())
])

df = spark.read.csv("path_to_your_file.csv")
df = df.withColumnRenamed("_c0", "c1")\
       .withColumnRenamed("_c1", "c2")\
       .withColumnRenamed("_c2", "c3")\
       .withColumnRenamed("_c3", "json_col")

df = df.withColumn("json_col", from_json("json_col", json_schema))
df = df.select(
    col("json_col.col1").alias("col1"),
    col("json_col.col2").alias("col2"),
    col("json_col.col3").alias("col3")
)

df.show()

spark.stop()
```

Comment: was this AI generated?